# Disable windows key in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application, node-webkit, nwjs

I'm making an electron desktop app. I want to disable windows key and function keys while the app is on

I tried using the following code ... it registers the event but the windows menu opens anyways

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "windows key pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

Any help?

Comment: To put it simply, you can't. [More information](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1395)

Comment: That's an issue from 2015. Check https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md They added the 'Super' Accelerator for Windows

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but unforunately it will become a global shortcut, meaning when the window doesn't have focus it will still be registered. Try putting a `console.log()` to see when it fires. `win` is your electron window variable

```
const {app, globalShortcut} = require('electron');

win = new BrowserWindow();

globalShortcut.register('Super', () => {
  if (win.isFocused()) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

You can check the docs here: [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md)

Or try to use this module here: [electron-localshortcut](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-localshortcut)

```
electronLocalshortcut.register(win, 'Super', () => {
    console.log('Windows Button pressed');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I put the code in my main.js ... this works ... but when i use 'Super' instead of 'CTrl+A' the app breaks ... electronLocalshortcut.register(mainWindow, 'Ctrl+A', () => {
        console.log('You pressed ctrl & A');
    });

Comment: What's the Error?

Comment: @VladNeacsu I know this is old, but I believe the binding function can not register singular expressions like `Super`, `Ctrl` and etc (has to be `Super+Something`, `ctrl+a` and not just `ctrl` or `super`). Do you have any other conceptions?

Comment: See the github issue regarding this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9206
Basically shortcuts that windows already uses (Super, Super+V) cant be used. The globalShortcut.register-function will also return a boolean indicating if it was successful. To implement this anyway use othery libraries like the one stated in the issue.